# Trailing slash before a query string. Bad practice?

Tags: url, query-string, trailing-slash

I have a URL like `www.example.com/store/`, which leads to a store page

When a user clicks on a discount link, it adds the parameter `?discount=foo`, so my link looks like this: `www.example.com/store/?discount=foo`.

Everything is functional. But is it bad practice to have the forward slash before the query string in this situation?

Comment: It's neither bad practice nor discouraged - in fact, Apache is often configured to add that / if it's not there.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It’s valid:

1. The [path component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) may end with a slash (`/`).
2. The [query component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) starts with the first question mark (`?`) in the URI.